# Custom annotation properties to store URL from database (inheritance issue?)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

My Annotations are placed on the map like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < [results count]; i++) {
        // create new object CustomAnnotation
        myAnn = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
        // set the lat and long of the object
        location.latitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        location.longitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];
        // set properties of the object
        myAnn.coordinate = location;
        myAnn.title = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
        myAnn.subtitle = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"strap"];
        myAnn.pinId = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        myAnn.url = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"link"];
        myAnn.dateTime = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"timestamp"];

        // add the object to the array locations
        [locations addObject:myAnn];
    }
```

In my method for `calloutAccessoryTapped` I am trying to get the myAnn.url value so that I can open it in Safari. The method which does this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    NSString *annTitle = view.annotation.title;
    NSLog(@"hello %@", annTitle);
}
```

However I cannot access view.annotation.url which sucks. Is there a way to get the url value of myAnn? myAnn is a object CustomAnnotation (where things like @property url are defined) which has:

```
@interface CustomAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
```

I was hoping that view.annotation.url would be inherited, but looking again, I am not accessing `CustomAnnotation`.

So my question is, when clicking the detail disclosure button, can I get the url of the annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    CustomAnnotation *annotation = (CustomAnnotation *)view.annotation;
    NSURL *selectedURL = annotation.url;
}
```